# синхронизация записи в openCL

Tags: opencl

Есть переменная типа `float` нужно перед записью проверить меньше ли она текущего значения в буфере если да то записать.

Как сделать так чтобы одновременно это действие мог выполнять только один поток?

Пример:

```
if(a < buffer[i]){
   buffer[i] = a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Для целочисленных типов существует реализация:

```
#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_int64_extended_atomics : enable // в начале файла ядер

atomic_min(&buffer[i], a); // либо atom_min(...) в зависимости от версии
```

[Поддерживается](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/atomicFunctions.html) в любой версии OpenCL

Касаемо данных с плавающей точкой:

Нашел костыль [тут](http://simpleopencl.blogspot.com/2013/05/atomic-operations-and-floats-in-opencl.html).

Comment: а с float сработает это же вроде только для int?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.